# Maps API using file_get_contents causes internal 500 error

Tags: php, google-maps, http-status-code-500

I have been using the Maps API service for a month now. This morning I found that the service has stopped working. Any request to `maps.googleapis.co`m causes my server to hang for a moment and then display the internal server 500 error.

At first I thought I was blocked / banned by google and there must be something I have overlooked with the `t` and `c`'s but having looked further there are no notifications in my google api dev console.

- If I make a request from another server using the same API key it works.
- If I make a request directly in the url bar with the same API key it also works.

It only hangs and causes a 500 error for the domain maps.googleapis.com and not any other. I am guessing that Google has blocked my server IP but it seems odd that they would do this and my API key still works fine. If they had blocked me it wouldn't it be the whole API account?

Firstly, how do I know if I am blocked?
Secondly, why do I not get a error from google saying what the issue is?
Why does it cause my server to issue a 500 error? If my server is blocked it wouldn't just respond to say whatever the API problem is?

All seem very strange to me. It only started today. I am hitting the API with `file_get_contents` using php 5.1 on an apache server.

To clarify, the 500 error is on my server, I cannot see any response from the http request because it hangs and then spits out the 500 error.

Comment: PHP 5.1 ?????? Seriously? Have you got any idea how badly out-of-date that is? The last 5.1 release was over a decade ago. Is there really a web host out there that is still offering it?

Comment: Also, if you get a "500" error, the actual error details will be recorded in the server logs. A good quality web host should allow you to see the server logs for your site.

Answer (score 0):

And now after 3 hours of debugging it works for no explained reason. The only possibility that i can think of is that the hosting company has been doing maintenance and something they changed caused this. after waiting on hold for 20 minuts they disconnected but perhaps they looked into it behind the scenes for me. Pretty annoyed a whole morning waisted and although im happy it has resolved its still frustrating to not know what or why

Comment: try with curl ... to see what is happen.